# What should be the format of a string to convert into NSDate?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm getting following two types of strings from server:

1. `2016-07-28T12:25:31.922247`
2. `2016-07-28T13:39:13`

---

I want to convert them into NSDate. I'm using following snippet to convert but it's failing:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"
```

I'm not getting the desired output.

Comment: Why the 1st date has .922247 data?

Comment: i don't know exactly. i think it's precision.

Comment: I'm not sure what's with down voting every answer, but if they aren't solving your problem perhaps try explaining it better, since each of them substantially explains the only visible problem here.

Comment: @DavidBerry Agree, its weird why they are down voting the question and even all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you doesn't care the fraction of second then you can remove it like this.

```
var strDate = "2016-07-28T12:25:31.922247"
if strDate.rangeOfString(".") != nil{
     let arr = strDate.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
     strDate = arr[0]
}
//Now you can convert this string to date using same date format
let formatter= NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
let date = formatter.dateFromString(strDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the exact format from this [Link](http://nsdateformatter.com)

For the second string use this

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date format works in `2016-07-28T13:39:13` but add `'T'`

Example: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`.

But for the `2016-07-28T12:25:31.922247` you need clarifies that this means `922247`

the truth had never seen anything like it, but I would try with `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the "T" (or any alpha characters that should be present in literal form), try:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

Note that this will only parse your second string.  To parse your first string you'll need to use:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S"
```

if you care about the fractional seconds.  Since `NSDateFormatter` is a literal parser it doesn't allow you to easily parse either format, if you have to parse both you'll just need to pass it to one, if that fails pass to the other.

Comment: One other caveat, the internal storage format is integral milliseconds, so parsed time will never be accurate to more than 3 decimal places.